# Recuperar todos os checkboxs marcados

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho esso código que retorna uma lista do banco com um checkbox ao lado de cada, no entanto quando envio ele via post só pega o ultimo marcado e não todos:

Exemplo com vardump onde marquei todos:

```
array(2) { ["seriais"]=> string(10) "3040156800" ["enviar"]=> string(9) "Solicitar" }
```

só que quero recuperar todos os checkboxs marcados, e só retorna o último.

FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="teste.php" id="ajax_form">
<table align="left">
<tr>        
<?

  $query_tpex = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.* , b.* , c.*,d.* , e.* FROM controle_contratos a, reparaveis b, projetos c, contratos d, empresa e WHERE a.status = 'Recebida' and a.id_contrato = '$numero_contrato' and a.id_pn = '$id_pn' and a.data_coleta <> '0000-00-00' and a.id_pn = b.id_pn and a.id_projeto = c.id_projeto and a.id_contrato = d.id_contrato and d.id_empresa = e.id_empresa");

  while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($query_tpex)){

  ?>
    <br>
 <input type="checkbox" class='marcar' name="seriais"  value="<?=$linha['ordem_servico']; ?>" />

  <? echo "O.S:"." ".$linha['ordem_servico']."-------- Serial: ".$linha['sn']; ?></label>

  <? } ?>
  </tr>

  <tr><br>
  </button><button id='todos' type="button" onclick='marcardesmarcar();'>Marcar/Desmarcar</button>
    <br>    <label><input type="submit" class="but but-success" name="enviar" value="Solicitar" /></label>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque colchetes no `name` do `input`:

```
<input type="checkbox" class='marcar' name="seriais[]"  value="<?=$linha['ordem_servico']; ?>" />
```

Dessa forma ele vai enviar um array com todos os valores selecionados, que você poderá pegar no `PHP` com:

```
$seriais = $_POST['seriais'];
```

Comment: Valeu meu amigo! Isso mesmo deu certo! Abraço!